# php str_replace not working with special $ symbol

Tags: php

I have a string:

```
$html = '${from_username} thinks ${to_username} is awesomelylylylly amazing';
```

I am trying to replace

```
${from_username}
```

to

```
$data->from_username
```

I am doing

```
str_replace("\${from_username}", $data->from_username,  $html);
```

however $html is untouched

Comment: str_replace will return the replacement string .. $html=str_replace("\${from_username}", $data->from_username,  $html);

Answer (score 1):

try this code: If you use double quote inside the string, It'll be treated as PHP variable. So try ith single quote.

```
str_replace('${from_username}', $data->from_username,  $html);
```

Answer (score 1):

And because it is friday and we are all impulsive morons my first answer:

> Use `str_replace('${from_username}', $data->from_username,  $html);`
>
> Single quotation marks won't search the string for variables and and
>   thus will ignore the $

is incorrect. As mentioned in the comments your real problem is, that str_replace returns the new string and wont touch the passed arguments. And the $ will be ignored because you escaped it correctly.

Comment: no need to use backslash when using single quotes to escape `$`

Comment: Yeah that was totally what was incorrect and not even the issue ;)

Comment: Edited that now, so I won't confuse anyone.